# How to fetch delta lines covered in code coverage of old code in sonar

Tags: sonarqube, code-coverage, cicd

I have existing test cases for app.java, and its line coverage is 45 out of 164 (45/164). I've recently added a few more test cases to app.java, and now the line coverage is 113 out of 164 (113/164), with 68 additional lines covered due to the addition of new test cases. In Sonar, coverage is shown only for the new code, not the lines covered in existing code. Is there any way to find which 68 lines were covered after adding new test cases

Sonar Version: Sonar Version 7.9.3